# How can I get string of the UITextField in customTableViewCell and save it to coreData?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, tableview

```
let  save  = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
var price =  " "
// config cell here
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "priceCell", for: indexPath) as! PriceTableViewCell
    cell.priceTextField.text = numberFromKeyPad
    price = cell.priceTextField.text!
    return cell
}
```

here it saves the price to coreData

```
@IBAction func saveButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    save.check.price = Int64 (price)!//here i have this error :Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional val
    PersistentService.saveContext()
    print(NSHomeDirectory())
}
```

what is this error in core data?

Comment: what is `check`?

Comment: check is a var in app delegate
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var check = Checks(context: PersistentService.context)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Ok Declare the Price variable like 

var price:String?

    before assigning the value to price check whether pricetextfield contains the value or not

if let priceValue = cell.priceTextField.text {
   price =  priceValue
}
and again before calling save.check.price = Int64 (price)! check for value

if let price = price {
   save.check.price = price
}
```

Comment: can you please more explain?

Comment: As per the error message and your code, you are force unwrapping the nil priceTextFeildvalue to price object, that's why before assigning the value to price, check whether textfield value is not nil.

Comment: declaring optional price object is upto you , As you are storing it in DB it doesn't make any sense to store nil value for price

Comment: no, it isn't nil when it has number i get that error